# Unable to download file (page url same as download url)

Tags: c#, web, download

I'm trying to download a zip file (that is normally accessed/downloaded by pressing a button on a web page) using C#.

Normally the file is downloaded by selecting "Data Export" and then clicking the "SEARCH" button at this URL:

http://insynsok.fi.se/SearchPage.aspx?reporttype=0&culture=en-GB&fromdate=2016-05-30&tomdate=2016-06-03

If trigger the download manually on the webpage and then copy the download url from the 'Downloads' view of chrome or firefox I get the exact same URL as above. When I paste that in a browser window I will not trigger the download, instead the above page will be loaded and I have to trigger the download manually in the same way as in the first place.
I've also tried using the network tab of the inspector to copy the request header of the request that is triggered when clicking the "SEARCH" button, but that URL is also the same as the one above.

Trying with C# I get the same result, the page itself is downloaded. My code looks as follows:

```
        using (var client = new WebClient())
        {
            client.DownloadFile("http://insynsok.fi.se/SearchPage.aspx?reporttype=0&culture=sv-SE&fromdate=2016-05-30&tomdate=2016-06-03", "zipfile.zip");
        }
```

My guess is that my code is correct, but how do I get the correct URL to be able to download the file directly?

Comment: The website probably requires one or more cookies along with the URL. Use Fiddler2 to see everything that is sent to the server at the moment that you initiate the download.

Comment: Any ideas on what to look for? What I do find in the request header is "Cookie: ASP.NET_SessionId=25h5ps55ri2etdnzhmqn5w55; insynsok=ffffffffc3a01c7b45525d5f4f58455e445a4a423660; WT_FPC=id=3da67408-37fb-49e1-812e-98a615bc5f47:lv=1465178890938:ss=1465178590640". I guess this implicates that some cookie info is sent when triggering the download? @KeithPayne

Comment: That is the cookie. You will need to receive the name-value pairs from the page containing the download button. Then send the same values back when initiating the download. See this http://www.hoonzis.com/screen-scraping-in-c-using-webclient/ for a good example.

Answer (score -2):

ASP.net inserts a bunch of crap into the the page to make things like this particularly hard. (Validation tokens, form tokens, etc).

Your best bet is to use a python library called Mechanize, or if you want to stick to C# you can use Selenium or C# WebBrowser.  This will fully automate visiting the page (you can render the C# WebBrowser invisible), then just click the button to trigger the download programatically.